# Checking list of enums with Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, enums, java-stream

Java 8 here. I have the following classes:

```
public enum Role {
  Admin,
  FunUser,
  SeriousUser,
  ...
  BasicUser;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
  private String login;
  private List<Role> roles;
  ...
}
```

I'd like to write some code using the Stream API that checks for whether the current user is an "Admin" or a "SeriousUser".

My best attempt thus far, which works, is still not Java 8ish:

```
if (user.getRoles().contains(Role.Admin) || user.getRoles().contains(Role.SeriousUser)) {
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to perform this enum check for several "cherry picked" roles via the Java 8 Stream API?

Comment: Any reason to use `List<Role>` (order important, supporting duplicates needed) instead of `Set<Role>` which could be an `EnumSet<Role>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other option:

```java
if(Stream.of(Role.Admin, Role.SeriousUser).anyMatch(user.getRoles()::contains)){
  ...
}
```

Comment: No need for an additional variable, just `if(Stream.of(Role.Admin, Role.SeriousUser).anyMatch( user.getRoles()::contains)) …` and we are as much “Java 8ish” as the OP wants while not increasing the verbosity. Still, the original code was more readable imho…

Comment: @Nonika it would be better if `User.roles` was an `EnumSet` in the first place. Then, iterating over the potentially shorter set ({Admin, SeriousUser} is fixed to two elements) is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
if( user.getRoles().stream()
         .anyMatch(role -> role.equals(Role.Admin) || role.equals(Role.SeriousUser))){
   ...
}
```